# Enable Business Data Web Parts in site

Tags: web-part, central-administration, features

I am using SharePoint Server 2010 and we do have Enterprise licenses.

But what feature AND WHERE must be turned on in order to show the **Business Data** Web Parts like in the image below. 
Something tells me some feature somewhere in CA must be turned on?

[image: Business Data]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should enable the "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features" at the site collection level. You can find the "Site collection feature" management link on the Site Actions>Site Settings page under the section "Site Collection Administration".

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem it was sorted enabling the feature in the follwing post http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Fixing-the-missing-Business-Data-Web-Parts.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I rather not use PowerShell as I dont have access to the server, also scared of it!

Answer (score 0):

In case if you run in to an issue of Missing Business Data Web Part in SharePoint 2013 On Perm Version and Activating 
**SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features** feature didnt help , it could very well be a case of missing license. Refer this [article](http://blog.ksenthil.net/2015/03/26/sharepoint-2013-business-data-web-parts-missing/)